# Save customer's photo as ravendb attachment

Tags: ravendb

I use an openfiledialog to select the image and then I resize it to fit picturebox. How can I use the resized image to save it as attachment?

Answer (score 0):

There is an example in RavenDB's documentation about [storing data as attachments](http://ravendb.net/docs/2.5/client-api/attachments).

Comment: In the examples is used a filestream to attach the image, I do not know how to pass picturebox iamge to the attachment.

Comment: Do you mean something like this:

    using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream()) {
        pictureBox1.Image.Save(stream, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);
        byte[] image = stream.ToArray();
    }

Comment: That throws a nullreference object

Comment: Which object is `null`?

Comment: I've added that code to the openfiledialog, when the save button is clicked the MemoryStream is null.